# minikube --kubernetes-version URI fails. Can I use a customized localkube binary?

Tags: kubernetes, version, minikube

Can I use a custom kubernetes version in which I have made some code modifications? I wanted to use the `--kubernetes-version string` flag to use a customized kubernete localkube binary. It is possible??

Minikube documentation says:

```
--kubernetes-version string       The kubernetes version that the minikube VM will use (ex: v1.2.3) 
 OR a URI which contains a localkube binary (ex: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/k8sReleases/v1.3.0/localkube-linux-amd64) (default "v1.7.5")
```

But even, when I try that flag with official localkube binaries, it fails:

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/k8sReleases/v1.7.0/localkube-linux-amd64  --v 5
Invalid Kubernetes version.
The following Kubernetes versions are available: 
    - v1.7.5
    - v1.7.4
    - v1.7.3
    - v1.7.2
    - v1.7.0
    - v1.7.0-rc.1
    - v1.7.0-alpha.2
    - v1.6.4
    - v1.6.3
    - v1.6.0
    - v1.6.0-rc.1
    - v1.6.0-beta.4
    - v1.6.0-beta.3
    - v1.6.0-beta.2
    - v1.6.0-alpha.1
    - v1.6.0-alpha.0
    - v1.5.3
    - v1.5.2
    - v1.5.1
    - v1.4.5
    - v1.4.3
    - v1.4.2
    - v1.4.1
    - v1.4.0
    - v1.3.7
    - v1.3.6
    - v1.3.5
    - v1.3.4
    - v1.3.3
    - v1.3.0
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Two options come to mind:

- You can launch minikube with `--vm-driver=none`, so the binaries are installed in your local filesystem. Then replacing the binaries should not be a difficult process.
- You can create your own minikube iso and then use the `--iso-url` flag. In order to build the ISO, you can follow this guide https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/contributors/minikube_iso.md